# How to avoid default action by pressing back button?

Tags: angular

How can I avoid default action by pressing back button?

this is my code

```
@HostListener('window:popstate', ['$event'])
  onPopState(event) {
    this.open('ac');
  }

  open(form){
    if(form == 'ac'){
      this.router.navigate(['/']);
    }
     ...
  }
```

Pressing the back button takes me to the previous page and not to the one assigned in "this.router.navigate (['/']);"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The popstate event of the Window interface is fired when the active history entry changes while the user navigates the session history. It **changes the current history entry to that of the last page the user visited** or, if **history.pushState() has been used to add a history entry to the history stack, that history entry is used instead.**
(as documented here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/popstate).

So ***add a history entry to the history stack*** will help you change the 'back' destination.

**SOULTION:**
Suppose I am currently in "/page1" and I want to navigate to "/" when the back button will be pressed. Check the following code snippet.

```
ngOnInit() {
  history.pushState( {} , 'page1', '/page1' );
  history.pushState( {} , 'home', '/' );
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

this should prevent default action:

```
event.preventDefault()
```

Comment: This does not work.